# Java: Split sql row data into multiple lists

Tags: java

I have a class with multiple lists dependencies like shown below.

```
class Test{
    private List<Image> images;
    private List<Text> texts;
    private List<Video> videos;

    .....with getter and setter

}
```

I need to fetch data from database and split row data into these lists. Splitting the row is based up on checking one field data in the row data.
like..

```
Test test=new Test();
for(Row dataRow: rowDetails){
        if(dataRow.getSubType().equalsIgnoreCase("image")){
                        if(test.getImages()!=null){
                            List images=test.getImages();
                            Image image=new Image();
                            image.setUrl(dataRow.getURL());
                            images.add(image);
                            test.setImages(images);
                        }else{
                            List images=new ArrayList<Image>();
                            Image image=new Image();
                            image.setUrl(dataRow.getURL());
                            images.add(image);
                            test.setImages(images);
                        }
        }else if(contentModal.getSubType().equalsIgnoreCase("video")){

        }else if(contentModal.getSubType().equalsIgnoreCase("text")){

        }
}
```

Please suggest me the best way to achieve it.

Comment: show us what you havel alreay tried

Answer (score 1):

Since it appears that you don't have to modify or delete the lists from the test class, I recommend you to initialize the lists on either the declaration of those variables:

```
class Test{
private List<Image> images= new ArrayList<Image>();
private List<Text> texts= new ArrayList<Text>();
private List<Video> videos= new ArrayList<Video>();
.....with getter and setter
}
```

Or in the constructor itself:

```
class Test{
    private List<Image> images;
    private List<Text> texts;
    private List<Video> videos;

    public Test(){
       this.images=new ArrayList<Image>();
       this.text=new ArrayList<Text>();
       this.video=new ArrayList<Video>();
    }
    .....with getter and setter

}
```

So you'll code would be easier as you don't have to test if the list has been created or not:

```
Test test=new Test();
for(Row dataRow: rowDetails){
    if(dataRow.getSubType().equalsIgnoreCase("image")){
         Image image=new Image();
         image.setUrl("some url taken from database");
         test.getImages().add(image);
    }else if(dataRow.getSubType().equalsIgnoreCase("video")){

    }else if(dataRow.getSubType().equalsIgnoreCase("text")){

    }
}
```

Also I recommend you to modify the Image, Text and Video class constructors to accept the parameters that your object needs, simplifying the code like:

```
Test test=new Test();
for(Row dataRow: rowDetails){
    if(dataRow.getSubType().equalsIgnoreCase("image")){
            test.getImages().add(new Image("some url taken from database"));
    }else if(dataRow.getSubType().equalsIgnoreCase("video")){

    }else if(dataRow.getSubType().equalsIgnoreCase("text")){

    }
  }
```

If you want to avoid the use of the if and else blocks, the best way here is to use a switch block as:

```
Test test=new Test();
for(Row dataRow: rowDetails){
    swich(dataRow.getSubType()){
    case "image":
        test.getImages().add(new Image("some url taken from database"));
        break;
    case "video":
        break;
    case "text":
        break;
    }

  }
```

Comment: is there any way to use generics to avoid multiple `if` checking .